# Need to optimize an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I need to optimize this Oracle SQL query:

```
select /*+ INDEX(ex1 EXCH_RATE_BK_IDX) */
            ex1.currency_id as currency_id,
            ex1.underly_currency_id as underly_currency_id,
            ex1.type_id as type_id,
            ex1.third_id as third_id,
            ex1.market_third_id as market_third_id,
            ex1.exch_d as exch_d,
            ex1.daily_dflt_f as daily_dflt_f,
            ex1.exch_rate as exch_rate,
            ex1.external_seq_no as external_seq_no,
            ex1.creation_d as creation_d,
            ex1.creation_user_id as creation_user_id,
            ex1.last_modif_d as last_modif_d,
            ex1.last_user_id as last_user_id
            /* security_level_e = 0 */
            from exch_rate ex1
               inner join ( select max(exch_d) as max_exch_d, type_id, third_id, market_third_id
                from exch_rate
                where currency_id = '1004'
                and underly_currency_id = '2'
                and exch_d >= TO_DATE('24-12-2009 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and exch_d <= TO_DATE('14-10-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                group by type_id, third_id, market_third_id
                ) ex3
           on  ex1.exch_d = ex3.max_exch_d 
            and (ex1.type_id = ex3.type_id or (ex1.type_id is NULL and ex3.type_id is NULL)) 
            and (ex1.third_id = ex3.third_id or (ex1.third_id is  NULL and ex3.third_id is NULL)) 
            and (ex1.market_third_id = ex3.market_third_id or (ex1.market_third_id is NULL and ex3.market_third_id is NULL))
           where (ex1.currency_id = '1004') and ( ex1.underly_currency_id = '2') 
           and ((ex1.exch_d >= TO_DATE('24-12-2009 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and (ex1.exch_d <= TO_DATE('14-10-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))))
            order by exch_d desc nulls last
;
```

Table creating script and Index as below:

```
CREATE TABLE "EXCH_RATE" 
   (    "CURRENCY_ID" NUMBER(14,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID" NUMBER(14,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TYPE_ID" NUMBER(14,0), 
    "THIRD_ID" NUMBER(14,0), 
    "MARKET_THIRD_ID" NUMBER(14,0), 
    "EXCH_D" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DAILY_DFLT_F" NUMBER(3,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EXCH_RATE" NUMBER(23,14) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EXTERNAL_SEQ_NO" NUMBER(20,0), 
    "CREATION_D" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "CREATION_USER_ID" NUMBER(14,0), 
    "LAST_MODIF_D" TIMESTAMP (6), 
    "LAST_USER_ID" NUMBER(14,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "EXCH_RATE_DAILY_DFLT_CHK" CHECK (daily_dflt_f in (0, 1)) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_701001" FOREIGN KEY ("CURRENCY_ID")
      REFERENCES "D_ORA_22_1_AAAMAINDB"."CURRENCY" ("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_701002" FOREIGN KEY ("UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID")
      REFERENCES "D_ORA_22_1_AAAMAINDB"."CURRENCY" ("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_701003" FOREIGN KEY ("TYPE_ID")
      REFERENCES "D_ORA_22_1_AAAMAINDB"."TYPE" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_701004" FOREIGN KEY ("THIRD_ID")
      REFERENCES "D_ORA_22_1_AAAMAINDB"."THIRD_PARTY" ("ID") ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "FK_701005" FOREIGN KEY ("MARKET_THIRD_ID")
      REFERENCES "D_ORA_22_1_AAAMAINDB"."THIRD_PARTY" ("ID") ENABLE
   ) 

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "EXCH_RATE_BK_IDX" ON "EXCH_RATE" ("CURRENCY_ID", "EXCH_D", "UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID", "TYPE_ID", "THIRD_ID", "MARKET_THIRD_ID")
```

Explain plan:

```
Explain plan
Plan hash value: 471245728
 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                  |     1 |   259 |    29   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                |                  |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT GROUP BY                        |                  |     1 |   259 |    29   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN                           |                  |     1 |   259 |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | EXCH_RATE_BK_IDX |  2291 |   174K|    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| EXCH_RATE        |  2291 |   404K|    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | EXCH_RATE_BK_IDX |     9 |       |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("EX1"."EXCH_D"=MAX("EXCH_D"))
   3 - access(SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("EX1"."TYPE_ID")=SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("TYPE_ID") AND 
              SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("EX1"."THIRD_ID")=SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("THIRD_ID") AND 
              SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("EX1"."MARKET_THIRD_ID")=SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL("MARKET_THIRD_ID"))
   4 - access("CURRENCY_ID"=1004 AND "EXCH_D">=TIMESTAMP' 2009-12-24 00:00:00' AND 
              "UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID"=2 AND "EXCH_D"<=TIMESTAMP' 2012-10-14 00:00:00')
       filter("UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID"=2)
   6 - access("EX1"."CURRENCY_ID"=1004 AND "EX1"."EXCH_D">=TIMESTAMP' 2009-12-24 00:00:00' AND 
              "EX1"."UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID"=2 AND "EX1"."EXCH_D"<=TIMESTAMP' 2012-10-14 00:00:00')
       filter("EX1"."UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID"=2)
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step in optimizing Oracle queries is often to remove hints that someone once thought helpful. :-)

Then you can rewite the query using a window function to get the newest row per type_id, third_id, market_third_id.

```
with 
  newest as
  (
    select *
    from exch_rate
    where currency_id = 1004
    and underly_currency_id = 2
    and exch_d >= date '2009-12-24' 
    and exch_d <  date '2012-10-15'
    order by rank() over (partition by type_id, third_id, market_third_id
                          order by exch_d desc)
    fetch first row with ties
  )
select *
from newest
order by exch_d desc nulls last;
```

Now, how selective are the conditions? What percentage of rows do you get by applying the `WHERE` clause? If it's a small part, say 1% of the table rows or less, then a composite index may help a lot. If it's 10% of the rows for instance, then a full table scan will probably be much faster.

You can try of course. Create the index

```
create index idx on exch_rate (currency_id, underly_currency_id, exch_d)
```

and see whether it gets used by the DBMS or not. If not, then this is probably about as fast as it gets. Well, you may add a parallel hint (e.g. `/*+parallel(4)*/`) then to use more CPUs for the tasks.

Answer (score 0):

We can't optimize your query without knowing what your data looks like. Even the execution plan's row estimates cannot be trusted because we don't know if your statistics are accurate. The fact that the plan indicates that dynamic sampling was used suggests that the stats are missing or inadequate. Removing hints and gathering stats may be all you need.

If not, I can make a few off-the-cuff observations:

1. Don't use `OR` in your join clauses, especially if it's just to handle `NULL` equalities. The hash join will work better with `NVL()` to treat `NULL` as a particular value that can be matched on both sides: `and NVL(ex1.type_id,-1) = NVL(ex3.type_id,-1)`, etc. It looks like Oracle has done this transformation for you: `SYS_OP_MAP_NONNULL` but it's better to do it explicitly yourself.
2. If the aggregation (`group by`) in the inner query block `ex3` really reduces its row count, I find it usually desirable to force Oracle to perform that aggregation within the block rather than postponing it until after the join to tables in the parent block. To do this, use the `NO_MERGE` hint to prevent view merging:

   ```
   from exch_rate ex1
               inner join ( select /*+ NO_MERGE */ max(exch_d) as max_exch_d, type_id, third_id, market_third_id
                from exch_rate
                where currency_id = '1004'
                and underly_currency_id = '2'
                and exch_d >= TO_DATE('24-12-2009 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and exch_d <= TO_DATE('14-10-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                group by type_id, third_id, market_third_id
                ) ex3
   ```
3. Your date ranges are rather wide (2009 to 2012). If there are only a few currencies (1004 is common) and most of the table are dated historical entries, asking for such an extensive period of time makes index usage questionable. You may want to remove your `INDEX` hint. In fact, just at first glance without knowing anything about your data (and therefore just making some assumptions which may be wrong), I would probably hint this for *full* table scan and some parallelism, as it appears more of a reporting query that will work on a significant percentage of the data:

   ```
   select /*+ USE_HASH(ex3 ex1) FULL(ex1) PARALLEL(8) */
            ex1.currency_id as currency_id,
            ex1.underly_currency_id as underly_currency_id,
            ex1.type_id as type_id,
            ex1.third_id as third_id,
            ex1.market_third_id as market_third_id,
            ex1.exch_d as exch_d,
            ex1.daily_dflt_f as daily_dflt_f,
            ex1.exch_rate as exch_rate,
            ex1.external_seq_no as external_seq_no,
            ex1.creation_d as creation_d,
            ex1.creation_user_id as creation_user_id,
            ex1.last_modif_d as last_modif_d,
            ex1.last_user_id as last_user_id
            from exch_rate ex1
               inner join ( select /*+ NO_MERGE FULL(exch_rate) */ max(exch_d) as max_exch_d, type_id, third_id, market_third_id
                from exch_rate
                where currency_id = '1004'
                and underly_currency_id = '2'
                and exch_d >= TO_DATE('24-12-2009 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and exch_d <= TO_DATE('14-10-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                group by type_id, third_id, market_third_id
                ) ex3
           on  ex1.exch_d = ex3.max_exch_d 
            and NVL(ex1.type_id,-1) = NVL(ex3.type_id,-1)
            and NVL(ex1.third_id,-1) = NVL(ex3.third_id,-1)
            and NVL(ex1.market_third_id,-1) = NVL(ex3.market_third_id,-1)
           where (ex1.currency_id = '1004') and ( ex1.underly_currency_id = '2') 
           and ((ex1.exch_d >= TO_DATE('24-12-2009 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and (ex1.exch_d <= TO_DATE('14-10-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))))
            order by exch_d desc nulls last
   ```

   ;

You may need to leave out the `parallel` hint, if your table is small and you're trying to get this sub-second. Parallelism has some overhead to get started so only use it for queries that would take at least several seconds without it.

Of course, if `currency_id = 1004` is *rare*, then the index is still of value and these hints should not be used. Only knowledge of your data can determine which is more appropriate.

Comment: "Only knowledge of your data can determine which is more appropriate" -- This is so true.